# Use Stored data into query SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, oledb, dataflow

I have a query where I take data, so I stored it into OLEDB Connection because I want to use that data several times into another querys

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
TT.VOUCHER,
TT.TAXITEMGROUP,
TT.TAXCODE,
TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR,
TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,
TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP,
TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
GJAERIVA.TEXT,
GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE,
GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
FROM TAXTRANS TT 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71,41) 
AND TT.TRANSDATE <= '2015-04-30'
WHERE   
(TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN  '2015-01-01' AND  '2015-04-30') OR (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND  '2015-04-30' )) AS T
```

Then I create another OLEDB connection where I have another query where I use data from first query

**Second Query (relevant code only)**

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
(SELECT TTRIVA.*,TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY FROM TAXTRANS TTRIVA 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TTRIVA.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71) AND TTRIVA.TRANSDATE <=@FECHA) TTRIVA ON TT.VOUCHER = TTRIVA.VOUCHER 
AND TT.SOURCERECID = TTRIVA.SOURCERECID 
AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRIVA.TAXITEMGROUP 
AND (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RIVA%')
AND TTRIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY


--JOIN PARA RETENCIONES DE ISR PAGADAS
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
(SELECT TTRISR.*,TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY FROM TAXTRANS TTRISR
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TTRISR.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71) AND TTRISR.TRANSDATE <=@FECHA) TTRISR ON TT.VOUCHER = TTRISR.VOUCHER AND TT.SOURCERECID = TTRISR.SOURCERECID 
AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRISR.TAXITEMGROUP 
AND (TTRISR.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%')
AND TTRISR.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY

--JOIN PARA IEPSCUOTA
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
(SELECT TTIEPSCUOTA.*,TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY FROM TAXTRANS TTIEPSCUOTA
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TTIEPSCUOTA.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71) AND TTIEPSCUOTA.TRANSDATE <=@FECHA) TTIEPSCUOTA ON TT.VOUCHER = TTIEPSCUOTA.VOUCHER AND TT.SOURCERECID = TTIEPSCUOTA.SOURCERECID 
AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPSCUOTA.TAXITEMGROUP 
AND (TTIEPSCUOTA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPSCUOTAP') 
AND TTIEPSCUOTA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```

As you can see I use `FROM TAXTRANS` in each `LEFT JOIN` but I have that `TAXTRANS` stored in first query. How can I replace that second query with first query data?

Data Flow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the need for splitting the query and merging it when it can be done in a single set? If you still prefer to have the queries on a seperate batching basis what I suggest is to first have the query which you would like to re-use be inserted into a temp table (# tables). Use that temp table to left join your other queries. Have it all encapsulated in a stored procedure and then get the data. To further enhance performance, check to see if you can incorporate indexes.

Merge join with sorting is a very expensive transformation and it eats into performance. Additionally what you are seeking is T-SQL improvement and SSIS transformations are not a replacement for that

Comment: I do it because second query is not the only one I have, I should do another querys like 10, and all querys uses  TAXTRANS info

Comment: If all the other 10 queries that you need to run are in the same database, then what I have listed above still applies. Modularize your queries in a step by step manner and have it run as a batch of statements at the database itself. Bringing the logic of joins into SSIS via Merge will not help.

Comment: Separate your queries into reusable sections and assign them to variables. Build each statement inside of an expression task prior to your execute sql task.